# Should I set "use strict;" in ionic 2 / angular 2 / ECMAScript 5

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

Just started a  ionic 2 / angular 2 / ECMAScript 5 project.

Maybe it's a silly question but what do you recommend, should I still add "use strict"; to my code?

I browsed some ionic 2 or angular 2 example but didn't saw "use strict;" still used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The "use strict" Directive The "use strict" directive is new in
>   JavaScript 1.8.5 (ECMAScript version 5).
>
> It is not a statement, but a literal expression, ignored by earlier
>   versions of JavaScript.
>
> The purpose of "use strict" is to indicate that the code should be
>   executed in "strict mode".
>
> With strict mode, you can not, for example, use undeclared variables.

If you write in Typescript then, NO - don't use it.

Comment: Because TypeScript compilator will add "use strict"; ... get it thx